# Access ASP.NET Web App as a Subsite on Sharepoint?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-applications, server, intranet

I've created an asp.net web application, which I want to access through the same intranet as my sharepoint. Currently, the main domain for my sharepoint server is salespace, so for example if I key in "http://salespace/flowers/lily.aspx" on my browser, it will bring me to my lily page which is under the flowers subsite.

I want to do the same for my asp.net application, placing it under the password subsite instead. So I would like to access my asp.net website on my browser in this manner: "http://salespace/password/reset.aspx". How do I achieve this?

Note: I don't want to convert my asp.net web app to a sharepoint site. I just wonder if its possible to import the asp.net web app into a subsite, then "borrow" the intranet of my sharepoint to run my web app itself.

Answer (score 0):

We can't convert ASP.NET web application to SharePoint Site.

According to your problem, as a workaround, we can do this via IIS filter events.

First, add reference of your ASP.NET web application in SharePoint Solution.

Then, we can create a [HttpModule] and remap [HttpHandler] to be the related handler of ASP.NET web app when the request URL likes "http://salespace/password/reset.aspx"